# How to select not null value if have more than one value

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns Customer_ID, Products, and OrderDate like this

[image]

What I am trying to do is If One Customer_ID have one OrderDate ( does not matter if the OrderDate is NULL or not) then OrderDate. If One Customer_ID have more than one OrderDate ( done is NULL and one is Not NULL) then OrderDate that is NOT NULL.
Target

[image]

I did try

```
select Customer_ID,
       Products,
       Max(OrderDate)

from table
order by Customer_ID,
         Products
```

but this one not work.

Thank you

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and the expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to them...) Also show us your current query attempt. [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do GROUP BY instead of ORDER BY, and you'll get a result. However, also take a look at @VikramSingh's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Select Top Number" to pick only one row, and "Order By" to order them by date so that if multiple rows exist it takes the top one, which won't be NULL unless all of the results are NULL, in which case it'll take a NULL.
Something like this:

```
Select top 1 *
from tablename 
where Customer_ID = IDNumber 
Order By OrderDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need all row, and if any customer_id have multiple value with at least one not null value then date in rest row should fill up with not null value.

You must use window function here rather group by.

```
Select Customer_ID, Products, Max(OrderDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer_ID) AS OrderDate 
From TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want one row per customerid/product combination, and to keep any order date that has a value.  That suggests aggregation:

```
select customer_id, product, max(orderdate)
from t
group by customer_id, product;
```